# Tomcat home page showing error

Tags: java, tomcat

I can't open my tomcat server home page it is showing the following error:

```
HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 1 in the generated java file
The type java.util.Map$Entry cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:102)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:331)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:457)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:378)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:646)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.23 logs.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.23
```

Comment: please share the jsp file with us

Comment: how can i share that jsp file here i am new here so please help @RoeyGolzarpoor Golzarpoor

Comment: edit your answer and add the jsp code

Comment: i have not dumped any code into the webapp folder i just wanted to check the home page of tomcat server @RoeyGolzarpoor Golzarpoor

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by a compatibility problem because you are using different Java versions. Likely you are using Java8 *only* as:

- JRE for your Tomcat OR
- compiling your code

Make a decision on which Java version would you like to use and ensure that your environment is consistently uses that specific version.